# Why string does not behave as a reference type?

Tags: c#, string

It might be because it's immutable.

```
    class A
    {
        public string a;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        A a1 = new A();
        A b1 = new A();
        string a = "abc";
        a1.a = "abc";
        string b = "ca";
        b1.a = "ca";
        a = b;
        a1 = b1;
        b = "cab";
        b1.a = "cab";
        Console.WriteLine(a);
        Console.WriteLine(a1.a);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

The answer is "ca" for a and "cab" for a1.a, and that's what I answered in an interview question and I explained the reason as "immutability" of string.

But the interviewer didn't look convinced. Could someone provide a convincing explanation of the above code?

Comment: Internally string is a char array. Arrays are reference types.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string - .Net strings are represented by this.

Comment: You are pointing `a` to the same value where `b` is pointing, in your case `ca`. After that you say that `b` must point to another value `cab` this does not mean that `a` is now pointing to `cab` it is still pointing to `ca`

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/636932/in-c-why-is-string-a-reference-type-that-behaves-like-a-value-type.

Comment: @DeepakMishra Probably because this is a basic misconception about how C# and references works, and as far as I know every introductory textbook explains this.

Comment: You might have gotten downvotes because you ask why string does not behave like a reference type when, in fact, it behaves exactly like a reference type.

Comment: ok I will edit the post by comparing it with a refernce types having different answer. If it is a misconception, then I would request you to please answer the misconception after that. It will help other people also who have the same miconception I have.

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis: Can you explain now?

Comment: Better Title: Interview question about assignment and reference types

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question has actually solved some of my misconception regarding string literals.

1. What does `string a="abc";` means?

I was actually considering  "abc" as the value which `a` points to.

But that was partially correct.

"abc" is the string literal which is itself a string object (created by ldstr IL instruction) as mentioned in the below link and the statement basically makes the `a` local variable point to the string literal

[Why don't we use new operator while initializing a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3328707/why-dont-we-use-new-operator-while-initializing-a-string)

2. What the below code meant to me?

   ```
   string b = "ca";
   a = b;
   b = "cab";
   ```

I thought `"cab"` as the update to the value which `b` points to and hence `a` will also be updated. 
I was thinking that value does not get updated due the immutability of string.

But as the string literal is not a value but an object which is equivalent to the below code: (hence gives answer to my question)

```
string b = "ca";
a = b;
string c = "cab";
b = c;
```

Answer (score 8):

This situation has **nothing** about immutability. It is all about how *reference types* works.

In your;

```
a = b;
```

line, your `b` and `a` reference points the same object which is `"ca"` and changing `b` reference to another object doesn't effect the object that `a` points.

Let me try to explain line by line what is going on here;

First of all, [`string`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.string.aspx) is a *reference type* and reference types have 2 parts. An *object* and a *reference* to that object.

In your

```
string a = "abc";
```

line, you have an `"abc"` object and a reference to that object called `a`.

```
string b = "ca";
```

In this line, you have an `"ca"` object and a reference to that object called `b`.

```
a = b;
```

In this line, now `a` reference points the same object that `b` reference points which is `"ca"`.

```
b = "cab";
```

In this line, you create a new object called `"cab"` and your `b` reference *now* points this object. It doesn't points `"ca"` object anymore.

```
Console.WriteLine(a);
```

In this line, since `a` *still* refers to `"ca"` object, this string will be printed. Changing the object that `b` refers doesn't effect it.

Comment: @SonerGönül Can you explain the edited code now? Why a1.a is coming as "cab" but a is coming as "ca" only. I am sorry if I were a little offensive. But this is slighly confusing to me.

Comment: @DeepakMishra This is the same principle as I explained in my answer. When you say `string b = "ca";` and after `a = b;`, now your `a` refer to `ca` and changing `b` to another object with `b = "cab";` line, doesn't effect it. And when you say `a1 = b1;` and after `b1.a = "cab";` since `a1` and `b1` points the same object, changing `b1.a = "cab";` will change `a1.a` as well because you changed (created new `string`) the object itself that **both** reference points.

Comment: @DeepakMishra And remember, in `string a = "abc";` line, `a` is a local variable but in `a1.a = "abc"` line, `a` is a field of `A` class.

Comment: @SonerGönül: When you said a is the field of A class, you actually answered my question. One more thing I would like to add here that references are not transitive i.e a1=b1; b1=c1; would not cause a1=c1 and a1=b1 would also not be valid. Thanks for the answers which made me to research further but still I am not able to understand the reason of downvotes.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't the case of immutability of strings. The string is a reference type. Initially, you set `a` to point to a string with value "abc". While you set `b` to point to a string with value `ca`. Later, you set `a` be equals to `b`. Since they are both reference types, the `a` now points, where `b` points to. In other words now `a` points to `ca`. Later you just change where `b` points to. This change doesn't affect the value that `a` points to.

Comment: Good one, because I understood your answer in less time than the more upvoted post because that was actually too long. :D

Answer (score 1):

This has more to do with the difference between pointers and references in C#.

With a = b, you don't point a to whatever b holds now and in the future. You don't assign the pointer variable a to the pointer variable b (the way C++ pointer act).

Because they are references, a gets initialized with whatever (string) ***value*** b holds at that moment. And that's it, any other ties to b are lost.

It's like a copy constructor, a new string value is created for a. When b gets changed again, a will not be affected. Because they hold different objects!

**Edit:**

Correction on the copying procedure: no new object is actually created. What's different from a pointer is the one-time assignment of the memory address of the object *at that point in time*. a will point to the same string value, in memory, hold by b *at that point in time* and that's it, no further ties to b in the future.

Comment: Your answer implies something that isn't entirely correct - after all, references are typically implemented as pointers. I think that what you are comparing in your answer isn't C# references versus C++ pointers, but C# references versus C++ pointer-pointers. Copying the value of a C++ pointer to another C++ pointer of the same kind by simple assignment doesn't introduce any ties between the two.

Comment: @Theodoros Chatzigiannakis, see my later Edit. I think we both (and Christos here below) are in fact trying to say the same thing: that's kind of a one time assignment of a memory pointer, with no further/future ties to the right-side object variable.

Comment: @CristiS. Thanks, I liked the way you tried to understand the actual question.

Answer (score 1):

While Sonor's answer is brilliant and correct it misses one important point. The whole point has **nothing to do with strings**. The puzzle works with integers exactly the same way:

```
class A
{
    public int a;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    A a1 = new A();
    A b1 = new A();
    int a = 123;
    a1.a = 123;
    int b = 31;
    b1.a = 31;
    a = b;
    a1 = b1;
    b = 312;
    b1.a = 312;
    Console.WriteLine(a);
    Console.WriteLine(a1.a);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

The critical fact is a1 and b1 being references. (Not a and b)

Comment: @Deepak Well it took me a few hours of thinking during christmas shoping... ;)